# (how) is it possible to choose the biological sex of a child?

Tags: genetics

I recently read of a study that investigated the ethics of child's biological sex choice in humans, and now I want to find out how this can/could be done. Does anyone know of scientific papers or journals that describe the methods in some detail? The answers I was finding in my own search were not as specific as I would like.

Comment: Do you mean sex selection? Keep in mind that gender and sex are not the same thing. If you mean gender then I think that this question is more suited to the cognitive sciences SE.

Comment: Yes you are right, I mean sex selection.

Comment: I mean that there is research involving giving couples the ability to choose whether their baby will be male or female.

Comment: The article you read had to do with `ethics`. So are you interested in ethics or in science? Are you interested in the methods that offer couples the opportunity to choose the sex of their baby or are you interest in how some species manage to chose the sex of their baby (which is particularly the case when there is environmental sex determination (ESD)). [This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_selection) might be a good start.

Comment: I read an article about ethics, but I wanted to learn more about the science behind giving humans the option to choose. I don't really care about the ethics at this moment, I'm more concerned with how it is done. I did some searches on Google, but I was getting generalized, nonspecific answers. I would prefer to find something from a journal or research paper that actually talks about the methods, success rate, and why it works (or why not).

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for a review (in a peer reviewed journal or not I suppose) of the methodologies that can be used for parents to chose the sex of their offspring, is that right?. You maybe want to make clear in your question that you are looking for a list of methodologies. The question is interesting (I am totally ignorant in the subject). I just wonder whether wikipedia is not already a very good source of information given how broad is your interest.

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you add some details

Comment: I looked at the wikipedia article you suggested; it does provide some detail, but I do still have more questions. I'll check the references there later in case those contain further detail. I did not realize wikipedia would contain that much information. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main technique is sperm separation or sorting, where you separate sperm by gender, and only use the gender that you want. Existing techniques aren't perfect. AFAIK, they are typically less than 90% accurate, but it is still better than 50%. Typically, this involves some type of cell sorting device often with some kind of fluorescent tag marker.

The second technique is embryo screening. Often, with IVF, you screen and can confirm the gender that you want before implanting the embryo in the mother.

Links:

http://www.fertility-docs.com/programs-and-services/gender-selection/select-the-gender-of-your-baby-using-pgd.php

http://www.in-gender.com/Gender-Selection/MicroSort/